# GIT ignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project for example `test"`.
In `test` project I have another project `test2`

How to do ignore some files from `test2` ?
I can only ignore all project `test` but I want to only some files from `test2`

```
project-test1
  project-test2
        someFiles in project
```

Comment: use a path? `project-test2/aFile` or `project-test2/` for the whole directory

Comment: You can also place a .gitignore file in the directory in which you want to exclude some files, and just list the file names or patterns.

Answer (score 1):

*Each* directory in the tree can have its *own* `.gitignore` file, you don't need to maintain some massive collection at the top -level. I consider this preferable since it localises the information to where it's most relevant.

For your particular requirements, I would place a `.gitignore` into the `project-test2` directory, listing the files you want ignored.